# Can not read file fully in c++?

Tags: c++, file

i have below code for read from file
I uplooded the file in http://m.uploadedit.com/b026/13886560748.txt
size of string in file is bigger that 113 but below code printed 113
**why?!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inf("Sample.txt");

    string str;
    string file_contents ="";
    while ( getline(inf, str ) )
    {
        file_contents += str;
        file_contents.push_back('\n');
    }
    cout << file_contents.size() << endl; // print 113

    return 0;
}
```

`UPDATE 1`
**So by open the file in binary mode problem will be solved .**
change `ifstream inf("Sample.txt");` to `ifstream inf("Sample.txt",ios::binary);`

Comment: Are you *really* allocating one `unsigned char`?

Comment: I edited the question please reopen it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read line-by-line joining them together with a `'\n'`, but a binary-to-text translation may be in place in you envirnoment: on a text file certain OS represent "new line" with CR/LF (windows)  or LF/CR (mac os) sequence, instead of just LF (linux).

This result in a file longer than what actually read.

Comment: So how i can read it? i want read all of content file and put them to one string.

Comment: read it as "binary" suppressing the translations: try opening it as   `std::ifstream inf("13886560748.txt", std::ios::binary);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read it bit by bit, this is not the best way to go.

you might want to try using `ifstream read`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
using namespace std;

//takes char to write byte to, and the current stream
//returns true if successfully read, else return false (aka. no more bytes to read)
bool readChar(unsigned char &r,ifstream &data){
    if(data.read((char*)&r,sizeof(unsigned char))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    ifstream sampleStream("Sample.txt",ios::binary|ios::in);
    unsigned char tmp;

    int byteCount = 0;

    while (readChar(tmp,sampleStream))
    {
        byteCount++;
        //If you'd like to read bits, use some bit masking here over tmp
        //and iterate over bits
    }

    cout<<byteCount<<endl; // yields 6715
}
```

[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/)

Comment: i see that the question is now edited, anyway this might come useful if you wanted to "read file bit by bit"

Comment: ok edited beacause avoid to close it .  +1 and thanks...